# Как получить данные из post запроса приходящего на мой сервер (http.server)?

Tags: python, http

Проблема в том что, на сервер приходит строка типа `"b'file=%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%$token=aawdawdawd$id=adawdwa"` а как вытянуть из нее данные, никак не могу понять

Данные отправляются так:

```
data = {
    "file": contents,
    "token": "wewfweo[f'ibw['oiebnf[",
    "id": "image_1.jpg"
}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/', data=data)
```

Принимаю на сервере:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

def do_POST(self):
    self._set_headers()
    print("in post method")
    self.data_string = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))

    self.send_response(200)
    self.end_headers()

    self.wfile.write(bytes("Hello World".encode("UTF-8")))
```

Comment: для удобства попробуйте [bottle](https://bottlepy.org/), flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

params = parse_qs(self.data_string.decode())
print(params['token'])
```

Comment: ругается UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 367: invalid start byte на parse_qs(self.data_string.decode())

Comment: Какие-то из пришедших в запросе данных не в кодировке utf-8.

Comment: пробовал decode(('utf-8') и .encode('utf-8'), ничего не помогает

Comment: Естественно. Использовать `encode()` на уже кодированной строке бессмысленно. Использовать `decode('utf-8')` на строке, которая не в кодировке utf-8 - тоже. Можете попробовать `decode('unicode_escape')`, но нераспознанные символы будут заменены знаками вопроса.

Comment: @Артур 1- application/x-www-form-urlencoded данные (которые у вас requests.post посылает) это подмножество ascii, поэтому вы не должны UnicodeDecodeError получить с utf-8 кодировкой (ascii это подмножество utf-8). Что-то у вас другое сломано. (проверьте что все данные прочитали, что Content-Length правильный 2- явный `.decode()` здесь не нужен `parse_qs()` сама вызывает.